# Merge rows in mdx

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

I have some MDX:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {
[Dim Investigation Report].[ID].children * 
[Dim Energy Object Full].[Name].children} ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[ID Distinct Count]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [acts]
```

It returns:

```
003022 2604171226005 Object1 1   
003022 2604171226005 Object2 1
```

How can I change the request to have result like this:

```
003022 2604171226005 Object1 Object2 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: So you have a dimension that returns member Object1 and the corresponding measure value for Object1. Then you have another member called Object2 that should have a different measure value (but in your case they both have a value of 1). It is impossible to have these two members returned in a single access with one measure value.